# phpunit @before @after not working

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I need to run a method before each test method. Based on the documentation https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.before, I did this little test:

```
/**
 * @before
 */
public function setupSomeFixtures()
{
    echo "setupSomeFixtures\n";
}

/**
 * @after
 */
public function tearDownSomeFixtures()
{
    echo "tearDownSomeFixtures\n";
}

public function testTruc()
{
    echo "un test\n";
}
```

The output:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from <root>\phpunit.xml

.un test


Time: 5 seconds, Memory: 14.25Mb

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've never used this, but.. isn't `@before` run BEFORE the test? And `@after` AFTER the test is done? So your output will only output the results inbetween the test? (Just a random guess)

Comment: The phpunit doc says: `The @before annotation can be used to specify methods that should be called before each test method in a test case class.`


So I understand well, @before is supposed to run before each test method, and not before the test case class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Before` annotation was introduced in the phpunit version 3.8 so in your 3.7 don't works.

This is my output:

```
PHPUnit 4.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /<omissis>/app/phpunit.xml.dist

The Xdebug extension is not loaded. No code coverage will be generated.

.setupSomeFixtures
tearDownSomeFixtures
.setupSomeFixtures
tearDownSomeFixtures
.setupSomeFixtures
tearDownSomeFixtures
IsetupSomeFixtures
tearDownSomeFixtures
.setupSomeFixtures
un test
tearDownSomeFixtures


Time: 451 ms, Memory: 23.00Mb
```

So upgrade to phpunit 3.8 or major

Comment: 3.*>3.7 not stable, I'll try 4.3 (stable)

Comment: Hi @smarber please consider to upvote my answer if you find it useful